# spark-shell showing spark old version always

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running macOS, and I have two versions of Spark: 3.2.1 and 3.2.0. I manually downloaded 3.2.0, and the older version I downloaded using sdkman was 3.2.1. I want to switch to 3.2.0, so I updated my SPARK HOME in .zshrc file as shown below, and I commented (also tried removing) older version 3.2.1, but it still shows older version when I run spark-shell —version.

I also tried below :
I removed old SPARK_HOME and kept only new one.
I updated the .zshrc file using , source ~/.zshrc
I tried to add the SPARK_HOME under .bash_profile
I have completely removed SPARK_HOME from everywhere still it is showing old version 3.2.1

```
   vim ~/.zshrc                                  
   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
   #export SPARK_HOME=/Users/A2001/.sdkman/candidates/spark/3.2.1
   export SPARK_HOME=/Users/A2001/Downloads/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2
   export MAVEN_HOME=~/apache-maven-3.8.6
   export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin/:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
```

Output:

spark-shell --version

version 3.2.1

Expected o/p :
version 3.2.0

I want to frequently switch to new and old version as per the usecases

Answer (score 0):

Update the SPARK_HOME, Source the .zshrc/.bash_profile and close/restart the terminal it will work

Comment: Thanks Devendra, but I have already mentioned that I have tried these steps.